# Why do people say "break a leg" to actors?

Tags: etymology, idioms

Frequently, before going on stage, someone will say "break a leg" to an actor, which is a peculiar acting saying meaning "good luck!"  How did this expression come about?

Comment: Because all actors are mad?

Comment: A good example of this is in the play/movie ["The Producers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Producers_%281968_film%29), though there have been allusions to the superstition in a number of plays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_a_leg), the term:

> reflects a theatrical superstition in which wishing a person "good luck" is considered bad luck. The expression is sometimes used outside the theatre as superstitions and customs travel through other professions and then into common use. Among professional dancers, the phrase "break a leg" is replaced with "merde".

The article goes on to mention several theories about the actual origins of this expression. The one that is often mentioned (as far as I have heard), is called the *Opposite Meaning* theory. It says,

> People in theatre consider it bad luck to wish an actor good luck, *so instead they wish the opposite, by saying "break a leg!"*.

Another theory claims that the phrase has Greek origins:

> In the time of Ancient Greece, people didn't applaud. Instead, they stomped for their appreciation and if they stomped long enough, they would break a leg. Or, some would have it that the term originated during Elizabethan times when, instead of applause the audience would bang their chairs on the ground—and if they liked it enough, the leg of the chair would break.[12]

Still another claims that the origins are, in fact, Yiddish:

> Some etymologists believe it to be an adaptation from the Yiddish translation into German. The phrase "Hatsloche un Broche" (הצלחה און ברכה) ("success and blessing") had been calqued from the German phrase "Hals- und Beinbruch" ("neck and leg fracture"), because of near similar pronunciation.

[The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/break-a-leg.html) (*hat tip to Unreason*) has even more theories on how the term came to be. They note that:

> 'Break a leg' also means, 'make a strenuous effort'. There are many references to the phrase used that way, which pre-date the earliest theatrical good luck charm meaning.

So the theories they offer stem from this. For example, the following things could be related to "breaking a leg":

> - Put on a performance good enough that you will have to bend your knee in a bow or curtsey to acknowledge the applause.
> - Impress the audience so much that you will need to bend down to pick up the coins they throw onto the stage.
> - Pass out onto the stage to receive a curtain call (the side curtains on a stage are known as legs).
> - Go on stage and have your 'big break'.

Note that still, nobody knows the exact origin of the phrase, but some are more plausible than others.

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/break-a-leg.html has few other possible etymologies

Comment: @Unreason Thank you for that link--I have added it to my answer, and credited you.

Comment: And how common is this idiom? Will it be understood outside theatrical environment?

Answer (score 3):

It's a superstition; wishing a stage performer "good luck" will cause them to have bad luck, so instead the person tells the performer to have the worst luck commonly thought of; literally breaking a leg on stage would be a very bad thing, considering "the show must go on".

Comment: It reminds me of _in bocca al lupo_ ("in the jaws of the wolf") used in Italian to wish good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "good luck" in theatre is considered bad luck. Just like saying "Macbeth" is considered bad luck or a bad omen.  (Instead of saying "Macbeth", people will refer to it as "The Scottish Play")

[Break a leg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_a_leg)

Comment: On that note... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h--HR7PWfp0

Answer (score 1):

Someone told me that a "leg" was a part of the mechanism that raised and lowered the curtain, the idea being that you could get *so* many curtain calls, your very popularity would end up breaking the leg of the curtain.  I find this extremely implausible but thought I'd pass it along.

Answer (score 1):

I like the "Vaudeville" theory from Theatre Superstitions". Steppenwolf Theatre Company. Retrieved 2012-06-30. that uses the "leg line" as its basis:
In the days of Vaudeville, companies would book more performers than could possibly make it onstage, but would only pay those who performed.[19] Since the Renaissance, legs have been used as part of the masking in proscenium theaters, which remain the most popular style of theater to this day.[20] Thus, to make it on stage, one had to enter the line of sight of the audience or "break a leg", to be paid

Answer (score 1):

My Director just explained to us that the curtains hanging either side of the stage are called "legs" in theatre touching the legs is a big no no! 
The expression "break a leg" means to walk past the legs (curtains) to come on stage! hence breaking through the legs!

Comment: Very appealing hypothesis, and one that's not pure conjecture. Could you provide a reference that says theatre curtains are called *legs*?

Answer (score 0):

*Break a leg* may stand for run, go, rush, don't have second thoughts, you've got what it takes to win. It is like hit the road, hit the ground running, hit the ceiling etc. which shouldn't be taken literally.

It is one of those idioms that is transportable and not necessarily originating from the showbiz. It's for assuring and motivating actors even more than "good luck".

Answer (score 0):

My own theory is that the English "Break a leg" comes from Jewish theater.  In Hebrew, "Baruch alechem" means "Bless everyone."  It's easy to imagine how, in America, "Baruch alechem" might facetiously be rendered "break a leg."

Comment: Ooh, I really like this. Could you provide a link which testifies that the Hebrew expression really means "bless everyone"?

Comment: Actually it's better translated as *Bless you*, which is even more apposite. It would be nice to have some corroboration from American theatre (theater?) though.

Comment: *Aleichem* (עֲלֵיכֶם) means "be with you" -- most famously in the expression "Sholom aleichem", *peace* be with you, or in Arabic, Salaam alaikum. *Baruch* ( בָּרוּךְ) means "blessing" (most famously in Arabic as the name of a recent US president).

Answer (score 0):

Had heard that during Shakespeare's time only the rich could afford to go to the theater.  Shakespeare however felt the poor should be allowed to see plays and made sure during this time that the poor would only be charged a penny to get into the theater and were made to stand not sit around the stage, front and center.  The story goes on to say they would be in such amazement being able to view these productions their mouths would hang open to the point they would drool onto the stage making it slippery for the actors causing them to slip and fall and potentially break a leg

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had heard that in early theatre the lead actors study or stand in would say it to the lead actor, hoping he would get to fill in for the lead actor if he broke his leg or any thing that would get him to go on in his place .

Answer (score -1):

I heard that a famous actor long ago, broke his leg during his performance, but In the tradition of 
"The show must go on", he persevered and gave the greatest performance of his career.

Comment: Do you have any idea who this was?

Comment: I've heard of football /soccer players who have continued playing a match with fractured bones, torn hamstrings etc., so as a story  it's quite plausible. However, simply stating "you heard" this story offers the OP, and everybody else, very little to go on. (Note that I didn't provide any names) It could also be that this incident happened long after the idiom had been established.

Answer (score -1):

I say break a leg mean example a comedy so funny you slap top
Of thigh so hard laughing you could break a leg.thus meaning have a good show.

Comment: Hi Arthur, and welcome to ELU. Citing a reference to support your belief would make this a better answer. Otherwise this can be seen as just your opinion, and we try to give answers with some kind of authoritative reference here. Since you're here, please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.